# Show that $A$ is positive semidefinite given $(B^TAB)$ is positive semidefinite and $B$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $B$ ∈ $R(n×n)$ and $B$ is invertible and positive semidefinite, show that $A$ is also positive semidefinite.

Comment: Are you aware of the reverse result?  That is, if $A$ is PSD, then so is $B^TAB$?

Comment: Also, you've given us the problem statement, but you haven't given us any context.  What have you tried so far?  Do you have any thoughts on the problem?

Comment: I've proven it the other way by showing $B^TAB$ is symmetric. Im unsure how to start this proof however.

Comment: Well, for the other way: it's not enough to simply show that $B^TAB$ is **symmetric**.  Typically, one proves this using the *definition* of positive semidefinite as opposed to (symmetry) + (non-negative eigenvalues).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** We know that $B^TAB$ is symmetric.  So, consider the matrix
$$
(B^{-1})^TB^TAB(B^{-1})
$$