# What are the conditions on $G$ such that $D^T G D$ is positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

**Problem Statement:**
Suppose that the matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ has the following decomposition:

$M=D^TGD$,

where $D \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ and $G \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$.

> What are the conditions on $G$ such that $M$ is positive semidefinite?

**Solution attempt:**

It seems that $M$ is positive semidefinite if $G$ is a diagonal matrix with nonnegative entries along the diagonal. Is there a more general statement that can be made regarding the form of $G$?

Is it useful to decompose $G$ as $G=X\Lambda X^{-1}$, where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of $G$ and $X$ is a matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors of $G$?

Based on this question: [Show that $A$ is positive semidefinite given $(B^TAB)$ is positive semidefinite and $B$ is invertible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140255/show-that-a-is-positive-semidefinite-given-btab-is-positive-semidefinite), is it sufficient that $G$ be positive semidefinite? Note here that I am interested in the case where $D$ is *not* invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed sufficient that $G$ is positive semidefinite.

First, If $G$ is positive semidefinite, then it is by definition symmetric. Thus
$$M^T = (D^TGD)^T = D^TG^T(D^T)^T = D^TG^D = M \tag 1$$
thus $M$ also is symmetric.

Second, for any vector $v$ define $w=Dv$. Then we have
$$v^TMv = v^TD^TGDv = (Dv)^TG(Dv) = w^TGw \ge 0 \tag 2$$
since $G$ is positive semidefinite. Note that if $D$ is not invertible, $w$ may be the zero vector; however this is not a problem because $0^TM0 = 0$, which is explicitly allowed (OTOH for this reason $G$ being positive definite would *not* be sufficient for $M$ being positive definite).

(1) and (2) together mean that $M$ is positive semidefinite.

Note however that this is in general not a *necessary* condition. For example, consider
$$G = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}, D=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$$
Clearly $G$ is not positive semidefinite in this case, but $M = D^TGD = D$ is positive semidefinite. As the answer you linked to shows, it is however necessary in the case that $D$ is invertible.

Comment: What about the case where $G$ is *not* symmetric?

Comment: @daneel: Then $G$ is not positive semidefinite, as symmetry is part of the definition. However symmetry of $G$ is only needed for showing symmetry of $M$, so if you don't require symmetry for $M$, you don't need symmetry for $G$.

Comment: Can $M$ still be positive semidefinite if $G$ is not symmetric?

Comment: @daneel: Yes, it can, if $D$ is not invertible: It can happen that $D$ just projects the asymmetry away. Indeed, in the example I've given, the only thing that matters for $G$ is that the top left entry is nonnegative, as everything else is removed by the specific $D$ given.

Comment: Are there specific conditions I can enforce on general nonsymmetric $G$ that will guarantee that $M$ is positive semidefinite?

Comment: @daneel: You must demand that any asymmetry of $G$ and any negative eigenvalue appears only in the kernel of $D^T$. Without having a specific form of $D$, nothing more can be said.